# java.util.Scanner refuses to take the next (or any) input

Tags: java, file, debugging, java.util.scanner

**Current error message** "cannot find symbol: variable nextLine in variable input of type Scanner"

Eventually it is going to do much more than this but I don't even understand why it won't read...so it may take a bit XD

Method so far:

```
public static void flipCoins(Scanner input) 
{
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines.add(input.nextLine);
        // WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    }
    System.out.print(lines.toString());
}
```

These are the links I have been trying to debug with:

**whole Scanner class**: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm

**.next() specifically**: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm

**EDIT FOR MORE**

I also receive this error: "**cannot find symbol: variable next in variable input of type Scanner**", with the following:

```
lines.add(input.next);
```

Comment: didn't you forget the brackets? .nextLine() .next()

Comment: Yes, I did. That will do it.

Comment: Please don't edit a question into an answer, as that doesn't fit into the StackOverflow format.

Comment: @MC Emperor -- I was in the process of deleting it and it warned me that I couldn't just delete my questions willy-nilly and had some sort of limit. How can I edit it so that it is still helpful, it doesn't get downvoted to hell (because it kinda sucked at first), and avoid simply deleting it?

Comment: @MC Emperor -- is this an adequate edit? I really want to leave it up but if this doesn't do it it's coming down haha

Comment: @KemperLee Well, not really. A question on this site should be a question only. Only add details to your question or improve formatting. But don't edit your question into an answer, or ask subsequent questions. Remember: you *can* actually answer your own question, by clicking the *Answer Your Question* button at the bottom of this site. In the meantime, someone has reverted your question to revision 2, which is probably the most suitable revision.

Comment: Thank you kindly for all the help on this. I have since answered one of my questions instead of revising it unnecessarily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing parenthesis"()", nextLine() is a function when calling function in java we need parenthesis after a function name to invoke a function. similar to what you did here

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
```

this will work

```
public static void flipCoins(Scanner input) 
{
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        lines.add(input.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.print(lines.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made this far more complicated than it actually is.

In java, method calls **must** end in parentheses; they aren't optional. Methods and Fields have separate namespaces - `input.next`, without the parens, is a field reference (so 'but why won't the language add it!' is a non-starter, it wouldn't be backwards compatible).

Just replace `input.next` with `input.next()`, and `input.nextLine` with `input.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
lines.add(input.nextLine);
```

Needs **( )** on the end of the **.nextLine()** because it is a void method within the Scanner class. it could even (but usually shouldn't) be rewritten:

```
String input = new Scanner(file).nextLine();
```

Because it is essentially just a piece of the Scanner object.